# Does Apache Ignite Custom Eviction Policy evict record based on cache attribute value

Tags: ignite

can we apply the customize off-heap eviction policy based upon cache attributes? (For example - Suppose, We store the Employee POJO object in the cache where status attribute value is true/false, is it possible to evict the records from the cache based upon status attribute? )

As per Apache Ignite Documentation, We can customize only on-heap eviction policy(By EvictionPolicy interface).is it possible to customize the PageEvictionMode also?

// Enabling RANDOM_2_LRU eviction for this region.
regionCfg.setPageEvictionMode(DataPageEvictionMode.RANDOM_2_LRU);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page eviction algorithm is much more complicated, than the one for on-heap entries. And unfortunately, as a consequence, it is less configurable.

`DataPageEvictionMode` is a enum. There are only three possible values for it: `DISABLED`, `RANDOM_LRU` and `RANDOM_2_LRU`.

You can find their descriptions by the following link: 
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions

Page eviction based on entries' attributes is impossible since entries are distributed among pages in nearly random order. You can't tell the page memory to remove some particular entry. Only the whole page can be evicted.